# I think we have a system problem that doesn't show new questions immediately [Problem Solved]

Tags: support

I once asked a Meta question "I can't see my question [Where does "약방의 감초" originate and what does it mean exactly?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/343/where-does-%EC%95%BD%EB%B0%A9%EC%9D%98-%EA%B0%90%EC%B4%88-originate-and-what-does-it-mean-exactly) as it was invisible for a few hours after I posted it. I deleted it after I could see it.

I am a regular visitor and I couldn't see the following three questions until an hours ago:

[Can you use -ㄹ려고 instead of -려고?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/392/can-you-use-%E3%84%B9%EB%A0%A4%EA%B3%A0-instead-of-%EB%A0%A4%EA%B3%A0)

[What is the difference between ways to say "motivation", e.g. 자극 and 동기 부여?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/394/what-is-the-difference-between-ways-to-say-motivation-e-g-%EC%9E%90%EA%B7%B9-and-%EB%8F%99%EA%B8%B0-%EB%B6%80%EC%97%AC)

[Meaning of 유리아이](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/396/meaning-of-%EC%9C%A0%EB%A6%AC%EC%95%84%EC%9D%B4)

Can this issue be checked and see if there is anything wrong with the system?

**Edit**:

**I have just posted a new question and it is visible on the front and main page.**

Comment: I have noticed the same sort of thing it seems. Some questions are very slow to post.

Comment: I think it'd be good to mention that it's actually visible in the "Questions" page, but not the main page.

Comment: @busukxuan Hello, busukxuan. I am not sure what is happening. When I posted my question, it was not visible on the front page and main page for a few hours and I couldn't see the three questions for longer than that on both pages.

Comment: I've noticed my questions sometimes take 15 minutes or so to be visible on the questions page. I'm not sure if all questions are supposed to be visible on the front page ('korean.stackexchange.com').

Comment: @topomorto All questions are placed at the top of the front page when they are asked and answered. It also happens when questions and answers are edited.

Comment: @topomorto Hello. Can you please check if you can see your question, http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/456/what-is-the-meaning-or-meanings-of-the-double-past-construction-%EC%97%88-%EC%95%98%EC%97%88, is visible on the main page and front page? I've just made a comment, but it is no longer visible to me. Quite strange.

Comment: @Rathony I can see it on http://korean.stackexchange.com/ and http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions...

Comment: @topomorto I see. Maybe this is happening only to myself.

Comment: @Rathony I think I have also observed delays. Initially I assumed it might be that questions had to be checked by one of the SE moderators before becoming visible, but perhaps not in this case. Have you checked if it's a browser caching issue?

Comment: Hopefully you can see http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/70/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site ? :)

Comment: Maybe it is just that questions are very slow to appear sometimes but as of now this question (http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/473/what-is-the-difference-between-adjectives-and-verbs) does not appear on the main page but it does appear on my profile and it shows up if I make a search.

Comment: @Lyle Hello Lyle. I just posted a new question and it is visible right away. I think the problem is solved. If you face the problem in the future, please let me know.